# r - Sum based on Distinct values on another Column

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for a tidyverse solution to sum a column based on unique values of an ID column, while still summing other columns based on all values.

Example data:

```
   dat <- data.frame(
        manager = c("Adam", "Adam", "Adam", "Bill", "Bill", "Charlie", "Dan"),
        manager_age = c(30, 30, 30, 33, 33, 35, 35),
        sales = c(4, 12, 7, 4, 2, 15, 10))
   dat

  manager manager_age sales
1    Adam          30     4
2    Adam          30    12
3    Adam          30     7
4    Bill          33     4
5    Bill          33     2
6 Charlie          35    15
7     Dan          35    10
```

I want to sum *all* values of **sales** but only sum one value per manager for **manager_age**.

Desired output:

```
  unique_managers total_sales total_age
               4          54      133
```

I'm most of the way there, but need help with the summed age:

```
results <- dat %>%summarize(unique_managers = n_distinct(manager), total_sales = sum(sales))
results
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Updated example data to include two managers with same age.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
library(dplyr)   

results <- dat %>% 
  summarize(unique_managers = n_distinct(manager),
            total_sales = sum(sales)) %>% 
  cbind(dat %>% 
          select(manager, manager_age) %>% 
          group_by(manager) %>% 
          unique() %>% 
          ungroup() %>% 
          summarize(total_age = sum(manager_age)))
```

Which gives us:

```
> results
  unique_managers total_sales total_age
1               3          44        98
```

Edit:

If you have two managers with the same age:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  manager = c("Adam", "Adam", "Adam", "Bill", "Bill", "Charlie", "Dante"),
  manager_age = c(30, 30, 30, 33, 33, 35, 30),
  sales = c(4, 12, 7, 4, 2, 15, 14))
```

Gives us:

```
  unique_managers total_sales total_age
1               4          58       128
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if there are multiple managers that have the same age. Consider a fourth manager who also has an age of 30. The desired total_age would be 128, but your solution would give 98.

Answer (score 0):

Attention: in order to avoid the case that different person have the same age, the `unique` operation on age should be within each personal group firstly.

```r
library(data.table)
dat <- data.frame(
    manager = c("Adam", "Adam", "Adam", "Bill", "Bill", "Charlie"),
    manager_age = c(30, 30, 30, 33, 33, 35),
    sales = c(4, 12, 7, 4, 2, 15))

setDT(dat)[,.(managers=.NGRP,
       sales = sum(sales),
       age=unique(manager_age)),
       by=manager][,.(unique_managers = unique(managers),
                      total_sales = sum(sales),
                      total_age = sum(age))]
#>    unique_managers total_sales total_age
#> 1:               3          44        98
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>